# Unexpected return of sorting a string()

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, loops, visual-studio-2012

```
  Private Sub bttSort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bttSort.Click
        DataView1.Rows.Clear()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim temp As Integer
        For i = 0 To list1.Length - 1
            For j = (i + 1) To list1.Length - 1
                If list1(i) > list1(j) Then
                    temp = list1(i)
                    list1(i) = list1(j)
                    list1(j) = temp
                End If
            Next
        Next
        DataView1.Rows.Clear()
        For m As Integer = 0 To list1.Length - 1
            DataView1.Rows.Add(list1(m))
        Next
    End Sub
```

I entered a string(1,3,5,6,7,113,23,62) After running the code above, the output should be sorted as (1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 23, 62, 113). But my out put was (1, 113, 23, 3, 5, 6, 62, 7).
I have no idea, hope someone can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The will onyl get the output you want working with int, long, double.. but with string, they sort lexycographically, which means..

1, 113, 23, 3, 5, etc....

all the 1's first.. then 2's... etc... ;)

Convert all the elements to integers, and try again! ;)

You will get the expected output! ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but could you please show me how to do that. I have tried "CInt", "Array.ConvertAll"... but nothing is working.

Comment: I think that if you create a int array, and then for example using a for loop in the string array, go copying all the values using CInt to the new int array... it will solve your problem ;)